# Issues associated with a single layer PCB for an RLC band pass filter

Tags: frequency, hardware, active-filter, cutoff-frequency

[image]

I have an issue the design of an RLC band pass filter with bandwidth ranging from 5kHz to 15 kHz.  I simulated the given circuit in Proteus.  It worked perfectly fine there. I then tested it on a breadboard.  It also worked there with almost 0.93 gain at midband.

When I moved the design to a single layer PCB, the gain dropped to 0.53.  The same components did a fine job on the breadboard. If the problem was associated with the components then it shouldn't work on the breadboard.

I don't know what the is wrong with my PCB design. Is there problem with the trace width or soldering?

[image]

[image]

I have attached a picture of my hardware. The layout was made in Proteus. I used a trace width 2mm.

NOTE: I also did a continuity check. No wires are shorted.

Comment: Seems like you are taking the output from the top of R1?  Did you take the output from there on the breadboard?

Comment: Possible problem:-->https://falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgoqoQFMBaMMAKABtwwVxCqUFCPKsNiRuDGIkIIsMwnkJEBxQZBYBjEP0FheWgVpQAWKOGgY8jcjCPEjtuEexGMmPNlWjWAJ32CUxn4guCZUXGoA5kEh0R6magDyQbpU2HgmKfEsAEqc3JmEGXphyPDg8VDQCCxJ2oYmaSYBoVAsAPYgJoWmXCjEYdBgGPgYYHAYRogo2NaikBB8IKosQA

Comment: Open-core inductor closeness might mean flux cancellation. Try taking out the middle inductor and rotating 180 degrees to see what happens.

Comment: @Buck8pe yeah, i m taking output from there, on breadboard and on pcb too